# How to have a static image in bootstrap's carousel?

Tags: html, css

Hey I am wanting to have 3 slides but to have a static image instead of each slide having it's own background.

I am not sure on how I would do so. Would you care to shed some light?

Comment: where's your code? http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Wrap the carousel in a div and apply your background to that. Use a transparent GIF or PNG for your slides, or set their opacity to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a transparent png image.

Answer (score 0):

Include image in static as well as template folder. Name images as image1.image2 and image3 and copy the below code in Html file and hence your carousel will work.

````
<!carousel Starts from here>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid pt-5" >
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100 " src="image1" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First Image</h5>
        <p>Welcome to Management Application </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100 "  src="image2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100 " src="image3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
<!carouel ends here>```
````